# Adding an NPM module to AWS Lambda Layer throws error: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module" when layer invoked from Lambda

Tags: node.js, aws-lambda-layers

Setting up an AWS Lambda Layer in NodeJS.

The steps are clear.

Setup the following directory structure:

```
-layer
    utils.js
    -nodejs
        package.json
        package-lock.json
       -node_modules
```

The `utils` file has a simple piece of code in it, like this:

```
export function get_exchange_rate(curr1, curr2){
     return 100.00;
}
```

The `package.json` file contains this:

```
{
 "name": "layer",
 "version": "1.0.0",
 "description": "",
 "type": "module",
 "main": "utils.js",
 "scripts": {
   "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
},
"keywords": [],
"author": "",
"license": "MIT",
"dependencies": {
}}
```

I zip up everything inside the `layers` folder and upload to Lambda Layers.

I attach the layer to the Lambda and my Lambda handler looks like this:

```
'use strict';

const opps = require('/opt/utils');

  exports.handler = function(event, context) {
     console.log("EXCHANGE RATE: ", opps.get_exchange_rate(1,2).toString())

  };
```

I run it and it works fine.

But then I add an NPM module to the layer. I run `npm install request`, this adds request and dependencies to the node_modules folder and updates the `packages.json` file with the request dependency.

```
"dependencies": {
   "request": "^2.88.2"
}
```

And in the `utils.js` file I add the following code:

```
import request from 'request'

export function get_status(){
 request("http://www.google.com", (error, response, body) => {
 console.log("error:", error);
 console.log("statusCode:", response && response.statusCode);
 console.log("body:", body);
});
}
```

I zip this all up and add to Lambda Layers, then call the `get_status()` function from Lambda, I receive this error:

> SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module

Comment: Is there a reason for this **nodeJS** subfolder? I think **utils.js** and **package.json** should be in the same folder. Then `"type": "module"` would apply.

Comment: This is the required convention of Lambda Layers, the nodeJS folder must be there with the node_modules beneath it.

Comment: OK, can you move then **utils.js** there too? The problem is that it being outside the folder with **package.json** the settings in that file will not apply.

Comment: Thanks for your help. Ok, did that, now Lambda throws different error, ` "Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodejsutils'` -- my require is this: `const opps = require('/opt/utils');`

Comment: since you moved the file you will need to change the path: `const opps = require('/opt/nodeJS/utils');`

Comment: Error: Cannot find module '/opt/nodej/utils' -- actually the 's' is somehow stripped out. Folder names are actually lower case. This is my require: require('/opt/nodejs/utils')

Comment: Tried it again, same code and it threw this error: "Must use import to load ES Module: /opt/nodejs/utils.js", so I changed the Lambda to: import { utils } from '/opt/nodejs/utils'; but now back to the original error: "SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module"

Comment: If Lambda cannot work with ES modules, you may try to remove `"type": "module"` from **package.json** and change `import request from request` to `request=require(request)`.

Comment: That's the answer! Thank you, sir (or madam) :)!